# Instantiating class in parallel leading to memory-related errors

Tags: c++, memory-management, parallel-processing, scope, openmp

The parallel loop below leads to several errors later on:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, omp_get_num_procs())
for (int i = 0; i < (int)my_vector.size(); i++) {
    cur = new My_Class(args);
    cur->do_work();
    my_instances_vector.push_back(cur);
}
```

Sometimes the program just segfaults, other times it gives `memory corruption` or other access related errors, other times it leads to unexpected behavior. Doing the instantiation sequentially and the work in parallel resolves the issues:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)my_vector.size(); i++) {
    cur = new My_Class(args);
    my_instances_vector.push_back(cur);
}

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, omp_get_num_procs())
for (i = 0; i < (int)my_instances_vector.size(); i++) {
    my_instances_vector[i]->do_work();
}
```

However, is there a way to have them both in parallel? I assumed it was a simple scope issue with the instance pointers, since each thread has it's own scope and afterwards I need to access the addresses of each instance outside the parallel region. The rest of the main program is basically

```
for (i = 0; i < (int)my_instances_vector.size(); i++) {
    my_instances_vector[i]->print_results(); // Should be done sequentially
}
my_instances_vector.clear();
return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

I tried all possible combinations of `lasprivate` and/or `shared` for both `cur` and `my_instances_vector`. It led to the same error or race conditions. The only "solution" I found was to unparallelize the instantiation. Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing or is it a error specific to the contents of my class? The class constructor basically defines the values of some fields based on the arguments passed. There is some dynamic allocation involved in that. Perhaps those addresses are being "lost"?

Comment: `cur` should be private (or declared inside the parallel region) and the call to `std::vector::push_back()` should be protected by a mutex (critical section). Z Boson's solution with private vectors is better since it reduces the time overhead.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why the chunk-size in the schedule is set to `omp_get_num_procs()`?

Comment: @Massimiliano We were doing some tests on the chunk size, no particular reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (as @zboson correctly pointed out) is a data-race during `push_back`. I would like however to propose a different solution, which may be easier to implement:

```
size_t offset = my_instances_vector.size;
// Pre-allocate space for the right number of pointers
// and set them to nullptr
my_instances_vector.insert(my_instances_vector.end(),my_vector.size(),nullptr);
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, chunksize)
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < my_vector.size(); ii++) {
    my_instances_vector[offset + ii] = new My_Class(args); // Create the object 
    my_instances_vector[offset + ii]->do_work(); // work on it
}
```

As you see the code is data-race free, as every thread works on its element of `my_instances_vector`.

**Not requested advice**: please take care of memory management! Using raw pointers in a vector may leave leaks in your program and will lead to code that will be hard to maintain as the vector is not in charge of deleting the resources allocated with `new`. I would suggest to take a look at RAII idiom and at C++11 `std::shared_ptr` and related methods (e.g. `make_shared` to substitute `new`).

Comment: Unfortunately the project I'm working on uses raw pointers and std::vector. Very clever approach, thanks!

Comment: +1 because your answer is clearly better than mine in this case. On the other hand, I can't think of a case I would want to use std::vector for performance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that std::vector is not thread safe. Each thread can increase the size of the vector and change its memory location. The way to fix this is have each thread write to its own private version of the vector and then you merge them in a critical section. In your case you can do it like this

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    vector<My_class*> my_instances_vector_private;
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, omp_get_num_procs()) nowait
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)my_vector.size(); i++) {
        My_class *cur = new My_Class(args);
        cur->do_work();
        my_instances_vector_private.push_back(cur);
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    my_instances_vector.insert(my_instances_vector.end(), my_instances_vector_private.begin(), my_instances_vector_private.end());
}
```

This assumes that `args` is a constant or that it's only a function of `i` and not e.g. `i-1`.